# Compare 2 values and only return the index

Tags: python

Let's say we have 2 Elements:

```
x = (123, 'aab', 1)
y = (456, 'cca', 2) or y = None
```

where `x[0]=Key, x[1]=Value, x[2]=Index` and `y[0]=Key, y[1]=Value, y[2]=Index`, where `y` can be potentially be `None`

Is there an elegant way in Python to compare the `Value` of both Elements with the `min` function and return the corresponding `Index`? Considering the case, that `y` can be potentially be `None`. For example

```
x = (123, 'aab', 1)
y = (456, 'cca', 2)
```

would return `1` since `min(123,456) = 123`  so `x` has the smaller value.
or

```
x = (123, 'aab', 1)
y = None
```

would also return `1`

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs and your desired outputs in each case ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but `min(x[0],y[0]) if y is not None else None` is valid Python.

Comment: @JohnColeman That returns the minimum value, he wants the `Index` field of the tuple with that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not pretty:

```
min((x,) + ((y,) if y else ()))[2]
```

The conditional expression will return a tuple containing `y` if it's not `None`, otherwise an empty tuple.

This gets appended to the tuple containing `x`.

Then we pass this tuple to `min()`, which compares the two tuples. There's no need to compare `[0]` explicitly, since tuples are compared lexicographically.

Then we extract `[2]` of the result to get the corresponding index.

Somewhat less cryptic is:

```
(x if y is None else min(x, y))[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store in a numpy array of type object

```py
import numpy as np
x = (123, 'aab', 1)
y = (456, 'cca', 2)
arr = np.array([x,y, None], dtype=object)

## Filter None Elements
arr = arr[arr!=None]

minimal = np.min(arr,axis=0)

print(minimal[2])
```

Comment: Will that also work when `y = None`? That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: Now works, I create a filter in array to remove elements none